# An error happened while reading data from the provider: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception

Tags: mysql, excel, powerbi, powerquery

Grr - I hate upgrades that break things

I have upgrade MySql Connector/Net to 8.0.31 from I think it was 8.0.28. And also the ODBC (both 32 and 64 bit) to same.

I think this has broken my Excel Power Query connectors which connect a spreadsheet to a database as I'm getting the title error message. Having similar issues with Power BI connectors as well.

I can't trace the inner exception as there is no ability with Excel / Power Query to do this unless I missing something. Other answers talk about this being security stuff but I have no way of changing/altering this.

Even more frustrating is that this message appears on some of my databases but not all.

The underlying MySql database is very old at 5.6.10 (and I have no way of upgrading this)

I'd downgrade back to 8.0.28 (at least it worked) but I'm not sure how feasible of otherwise that is. I get the impression

I can happily query via a SQL tool (e.g. dbeaver or MySQL Workbench) so this is something else.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Thanks

EDIT:
So I downgrade MySQL Connector t0 8.0.28 (by using Windows Programs and uninstall the various MySQL 'upgraded' component so that downgrade to versions I wanted)

Still had the error. It is very much a security issue and disabling encrypted connection has fixed most of it.

Like to know why this happened as not happy exposing more than I want too.

Phew.

Comment: you can try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46518563/net-mysql-error-a-call-to-sspi-failed-message-received-was-unexpected . Seeting sslmode=none

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to use an odbc connection string.

you'll need the MySQL ODBC driver instead of the .NET that cause the issue.

Download here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=513647

In powerBI go to 'Get data' and select more. On the bottom of the list of sources is the 'Other' option and about half way is the ODBC.

In case you need an example: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-2/